# Tkinter after() goes slow on Windows

Tags: windows, multithreading, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on a program that sends a list of points with certain rate/point to the Arduino using firmata. To test it, I took a program and modified it using `tk.after()` function. Also I had a `spinbox` to change the rate if needed.

The program ran fine in Windows with default rate of 1 ms. However, when I changed the rate to 2 ms or others, it can only run correctly when Google Chrome is opened. Otherwise, it would go significantly slow.
Very interesting thing to note is that when I ran the same code on Macbook, it ran fine with any values from the rate.

```
import time
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from timeit import default_timer as timer
root = Tk()
boxRate = IntVar()
isLooping = False

w = Label(root, text="Test")
w.pack()

frame = Frame(root, width=300, height=300)
frame.pack()

n = 0


def my_func():
    global end
    global start
    global isLooping
    global n
    if n >= 359:
        n = 0
        end = timer()
        print ("Total time: ", end - start)
        start = timer()
    else:
        n += 1

    #should be sending serial communication here

    if isLooping:
        root.after(boxRate.get(), my_func)


def run():
    global start
    global isLooping
    start = timer()
    isLooping = True
    root.after(boxRate.get(), my_func)

def exit():
    root.destroy()

def update():
    print ("Update")

def print_rate(rate):
    print (rate)

def stop():
    global isLooping
    isLooping = False

frequencyBox = Spinbox(root, from_ = 1, to = 100, textvariable = boxRate)
frequencyBox.pack()
frequencyBox.bind("<Return>", lambda event:print_rate(boxRate.get()))

runButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Run", command = run)
runButton.pack()

updateButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Update", command = lambda:print_rate(boxRate.get()))
updateButton.pack()

stopButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Stop", command = stop)
stopButton.pack()

exitButton = ttk.Button(root, text = "Exit", command = exit)
exitButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: At 1ms it runs ~0.37s then doubles at 2ms and triples at 3ms, etc `time = 0.37 * freq` more or less. `Tk.after` does not guarantee the function will run at exactly Xms every time due to any processing that takes place. Run it on 1ms and wildly move the window around, you'll notice that it takes more time because of the increased load.

Comment: That's exactly what I've been receiving. But when Chrome is opened with some specific website like Quora or Reddit, the rate becomes normal again regardless of 1 or 2 or 3 ms. That's what I'm wondering. Also, do you recommend some alternative to this problem that can delay for miliseconds? I used time.sleep() and it had the same issue.

Comment: I don't understand how that can affect it, it ran more or less consistent no matter the ms for me. Test again with task manager, maybe some other background processes happened to be running. `time.sleep` is a big no for `tkinter` `Tk.after` is the primary option. Or you can check out [threading](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html) which might help. Can't remember if it's `tkinter` friendly or not.

Comment: And another weird thing is it only happens on Windows machines (I tried on desktop and laptop both). I ran the same code on Mac and nothing wrong happened. Will definitely check. Thanks a lot.